# Ffmpeg: Convert video AVI to video AVI anamorphose

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, avi

To convert a video MP4 to video MP4 anamorphose I use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -crf 15 -g 1 -intra output.mp4
```

I get a perfect quality in the `output.mp4`.

I want to get a video AVI anamorphose, I use the same options `-crf 15 -g 1 -intra` but I got a bad quality of the `output.avi`.

What command I can use to convert a `input.avi` to an AVI anamorphose?

Comment: Which codec do you want in AVI?

Answer (score 0):

For MPEG-4 Part 2 codec, use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -q:v 10 -g 1 output.avi
```

Experiment with different values to get acceptable quality. Lower is better.